# Concat regex with a string in a constant declaration as oneliner

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am trying to declare a constant as an one liner like this:

`use constant HOME_SCRIPT    => "/home/george/". $0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/;`
The problem is that this returns: `/home/george/1`. I.e. it concats the number of matches of regex.
I tried:
`use constant HOME_SCRIPT    => ("/home/george/"). $0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/;`
`use constant HOME_SCRIPT    => "/home/george/". ($0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/);`
but same result.
Is it possible to create an oneliner for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use constant HOME_SCRIPT => "/home/george/". ($0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/)[0];
```

or

```
use constant HOME_SCRIPT => join "", "/home/george/", $0 =~ /(.*)\.pl/;
```

Comment: @Cratylus it takes first element of the list, `(list)[0]` so regex stays in list context as opposed to `.` operator which forces scalar context

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Perl 5 version 14 or later, you can use non-destructive substitution via the `/r` modifier. Like this

```
use constant HOME_SCRIPT => ("/home/george/$0") =~ s/\.pl\z//r;
```

Or if you are forced to use something earlier, or would simply prefer a different method, you can write

```
use constant HOME_SCRIPT => '/home/george/' . ($0 =~ /(.*)\./, $1);
```